# JQuery Load/Get executing scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I'm trying to "hijack" a ui for a website.

goal: Instead of opening links of webpage in tabs or windows I want to open them on a grid in on the main page. I'll probably using something like gridster. Basically I'll put a web page per grid element.

The following code demonstrates what I'm trying to do. For stackoverflow, it wraps the main page in a hideable div controlled by a small "button" in the corner. Clicking a link will open the it in the same window. To return to the "home page" simply click the button again.

The effect is very similar to tabs but the goal is to keep tabs more tabs free and also allow better organization. One could have multiple "buttons" to allow for multiple links all on the same "page". (one way to think about it is a sort of mini-tab feature where you access the tabs through very small buttons).

I want to actually have multiple elements per page shown. The following code only displays one question.

In any case the real issue is not the layout but that jquery.load does not execute scripts. This is a major issue in that some webpages simply will not work. There is no cross-domain issues since these scripts are injected into the the domain. The problem is that the scripts are either not executed or not executed properly. I've spent the last 8 hours trying various methods but none work.

The goal with this code is to take something like youtube(or stack exchange) and consolidate the links to a single page(if one desires). Think of the ability to browse youtube video's by having multiple videos(without all the extra information visible) on the same page in a grid layout. Not that one would necessarily want to watch 10 videos at once but it would be more efficient than having 10 tabs open.

Another way to think about it is if you have to keep flipping between sites you could easily load one site into one grid element and another into another on the same screen.

One could even have a very simple navigational type of interface to easily "scroll" through a website. Think of a forum with a thread with many posts. In stead of having to read a long list you could design an interface that simply shows the posts one at a time with a left and right button to move through the posts. (obviously these methods require specific coding per site but much of the code will overlap. The following code can be used on almost any site(at least ones that do not use absolute selectors) and makes it easy to get to the "home page" with just a click of the button)

The usefulness, at least to me, is extremely limited if it can't be used for pages that contain scripts. I can't fathom why it wouldn't work. A sandboxed iframe should work but has the same issues as jquery.load/get. I've tried executing each script after loading the html using getscript to no avail.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stackanator
// @namespace   http://userscripts.org/
// @version     1.0
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/
// ==/UserScript==
var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;


// Wrap main div with a div and style it to be floating
$('body').wrap('<div id="CBP" />');
$('<div id="CBPA"></div>').insertBefore($('#CBP'));
$('#CBP').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px', 'left': '0px', 'width' : '100%', 'height' : '100%', 'z-index': '9999', 'background-color': 'white'});

// Create a small toggle box to show and hide the main div 
$('#CBPA').attr('style', 'margin:0px;padding:0px;height:10px;width:10px;background-color:green;position:fixed;display:block;left:0px;right:0px;float:left;z-index:30000;');

// Setup toggle button
toggleCBPAs = false;
toggleCBPA = false;
$('#CBPA').click(function() {
    if (toggleCBPAs == false) return;
    if (toggleCBPA == true)
    {
        toggleCBPA = false;
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        $('#CBP').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else
    {
        toggleCBPA = true;
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        $('#CBP').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});

// Take over click's
$('body A').live('click', function() { 
        toggleCBPAs = true;
        var url = $(this).attr("href");         
        name = url.split("/"); 
        debugger;
        //var p = $('<iframe id="CBF" src="'+$(this).attr("href")+'" sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>').insertAfter($('#CBP'));

        $('<div id="CBG"></div>').insertAfter($('#CBP'));
        $("#CBG").load(url);

        toggleCBPA = true;
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        $('#CBP').css('visibility', 'hidden');

        return false; 
});
```

Comment: You have provided too much details but haven't asked any question.

Comment: You are abusing id, there shouldn't be two elements with the same id. and what's your problem? Does your code work till `debugger`?

Comment: @undefined Um I did, I said it does not work when the files include javascript. Please read. If you don't want to read then just ignore the whole question.

Comment: @xiaoyi um, yes, it is only test code... everything works fine. That is not the issue. The problem, as I stated, is that when the included files contain javascript they do not "render" properly. (beause the js is not executed)

Comment: I've tried this on latest chrome and ff...

Answer (score 1):

**First you cannot put stackoverflow.com (and almost all the big sites) in `<iframe>`.**

All the major sites are designed to prevent being framed, to make sure their page won't be used for fraud purpose. So there will be some script to detect if the page is displayed in a frame, and if so, it will do some suicide job, to make the page go away.

**Second, you cannot use `$.load()` to put the whole page in another div.**

Despite `$.load()`'s method to explicitly `eval()` on each block may execute the code, but it may break event handlers and some `$(selector)` references.

Some events (like onload) will never be fired, and some `$(selector)` will be wrong (eg. `$('#id')` will fail when the later loaded element share the same id as the one already on the page.)

Moreover `eval()` uses the same code context as all the other code running on the page, it will conflict with each other at the same time, so it cannot be considered as a solution in any aspect.

**Third, you cannot use `innerHTML` as a replacement to the `$.load()`, though the DOM looks right**

According to [script tag create with innerHTML of a div doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work), `innerHTML` will not execute the script. And my previous provided *possible* solution turned out to be insufficient.

**So the final answer is that it's impossible to accomplish using script using common methods.**

Some thoughts:

1. Build your own browser, that will assert `window.top === null` even in `<iframe>`
2. Manage to write a really smart script, that will automatically modify the code (html, js, css) retrieved to make it in conflict with the current page, and then embed the page in a `<div>`.
3. Manage a way to detect the code that prevent being framed, and remove it. Then put the processed code in an empty `<iframe>`.

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for what can't be done but what can be done. Is it possible with or without jquery to load a web page from the same domain **Fully** in to a div or iframe? By *fully*, I mean, that it will work as if it were loaded into a new window/tab.

Comment: Um, as I said already about 5 times... it does not work either. Same issues(the javascript code that loads a swf player never executes).

Comment: I've done this with the same results. I used jquery's .html() instead but it's suppose to be the same thing. IIRC, the <head> is loaded but all `<scripts>` are still stripped out. It is only suppose to be done for cross-domain security reasons but I'm not on a different domain so it shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: I tried about 10 different methods of getting the html(from using xmlhttprequest directly to using jquery's load. All have the same issue. I've tried to extract the <script> tag's, which worked, and execute the scripts but it didn't work corretly.

Comment: Trust me, `$.html()` and `node.innerHTML` is not the same. Give `innerHTML` a shot.

Comment: well, jquery contradicts you: http://api.jquery.com/html/ "This method uses the browser's innerHTML property".... so it's very hard to trust you just because you say so. Do you have any proof?

Comment: Watch out your words! I'm the only one help you with your annoying problem AND I never suggest my solution is the final one as your problem is specialized with stackoverflow.com. which even not a problem on other sites at all, just change the `@include`, and it will work proper with iframe on other site. If you take a look into the jq source, `$.html()` will not use `innerHTML` to inject html when detect there are `<script>` inside. It will use `$.append()` to process the html, and use ajax to retrieve scripts and `eval()` them in window scope. This is not the same  as `innerHTML`.

Comment: I don't need help if your going to be an ass. I've spend 8 hours and I did try innerHTML at some point but not necessarily using get. I'm also not trying to change the @include to work on other sites. Simply to get the scripts to execute properly when included loaded using get/load. I will try again using innerHTML and get but chances are it will not work... it is not easy to work with tampermonkey scripts because the editor sucks and there is no way to easily use an external editor. But if it works then jQuery docs sucks...

Comment: Using innerHTML doesn't execute the scripts. It does seem to load the script tags into the html. Both `$('#CBG').html(data);` and `document.getElementById('CBG').innerHTML = data;` both load the html AND scripts BUT `.html()` seems to stript some script tags! (not all though).  innerHTML does not work though. It is either not executing the scripts or not executing them in the proper context of the div. I will try to do the same thing on an iframe but I imagine it too won't work since it should work directly.

Comment: Looking at the resources between the injected page and native there are many more scripts loaded in the native. So while get is returning the scripts and innerHTML is injecting the html into the div, it is not executing them. Since I have tried to execute the script tags manually without success I do not think it will work but I will try again one more time.

Comment: Man, here is the thing. First, iframe should be the answer, this is the only proper way to run another page inside with isolated context. But most sites stackoverflow, youtube, etc, will prevent you from putting them in a iframe. Second, the code is executed when using `innerHTML` or `eval()`, but the context of the later executed code and other code on this page are the same, and some events handlers in later loaded code like `onload` will not fired for the event is fired only once when the page loaded.

Comment: Yes, and that is the problem! iframe does not work for my case. I have used iframe and it simply does not work. The page loads but the swf does not work. I have used innerHTML, eval, getScripts, load, get, etc... nothing works. swf never runs. Either the code is not being executed or it is being executed but not properly. Possibly because, as you say, the onload's are not running. BUT, again, it doesn't work in an iframe either and I would expect it to. So if if they are preventing it to run as an iframe the question is, how to defeat that.

Comment: No easy way to do it. Three possible methods. First, retrieve target page by ajax, and retrieve the raw data you need, and render yourself.  Second, retrieve all pieces of the target page, and remove the code that preventing click hijacking, and write them in a iframe's inner document. Third, build your own browser, that always give window.top === null, which should not be very hard. Oh there is a four, use Tile Tabs on firefox.

Comment: Well, I did mention something like that before. I was hoping someone already figured out some good way to do this which is why I asked the question...

Comment: Then you should start a new problem called 'how to iframe a webpage that prevent being framed', and close this one.