# script tag create with innerHTML of a div doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the JS code:

```
var wrap = document.createElement("div");
wrap.innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" src="'+scriptUrl+'"></script>';
var wrapscript = wrap.childNodes[0];
document.body.appendChild(wrapscript)
```

The body did insert the script element, but the JS resource wasn't loaded, there isn't even an http request.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

The problem is with Zeptojs's $ method

```
$('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+scriptUrl+'"></script>').appendTo($("bdoy"))
```

It works like the code above, and causes the bug.

Comment: this happens because the browser ignores the addition, thinking it is just html and not executable code. create a new script element using document.createElement or $("<script/>")

Comment: `$("bdoy")` is a typo, I guess.

Comment: Also, `.appendChild("wrapscript")` will not do what you're after. **wrapscript** there, is only a string (because you've wrapped it in quotes).

Comment: hehe,so sorry,the quotes is a typo,i have fixed it,and it's not the reason.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This one was trivial.

As stated in spec ([8.4 Parsing HTML fragments](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-end.html#parsing-html-fragments) and [8.2.3.5 Other parsing state flags](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#scripting-flag),) quote:

*when using `innerHTML` the browser will*

> 1. Create a new Document node, and mark it as being an HTML document.
> 2. If there is a context element, and the Document of the context element is in quirks mode, then let the Document be in quirks mode.
>      Otherwise, if there is a context element, and the Document of the
>      context element is in limited-quirks mode, then let the Document be in
>      limited-quirks mode. Otherwise, leave the Document in no-quirks mode.
> 3. Create a new HTML parser, and associate it with the just created Document node.
>      ...

*and when parsing a `<script>` inside*

> The scripting flag is set to "enabled" if scripting was enabled for
>   the Document with which the parser is associated when the parser was
>   created, and "disabled" otherwise.
>
> The scripting flag can be enabled even when the parser was originally
>   created for the HTML fragment parsing algorithm, even though script
>   elements don't execute in that case.

So it won't be executed, as long as you inject it with `innerHTML`.

And using `innerHTML` will prevent *the* `<script>` element created from being executed permanently.

As stated in spec ([4.3.1 The script element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-script-element.html#attr-script-src),) quote:

> Changing the src, type, charset, async, and defer attributes dynamically has no direct effect; these attribute are only used at specific times described below.

Concluding the *described below* is that, it only parse the `src` attribute when injecting the `<script>` to the `document` (no matter which, including the [temporary one](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-end.html#parsing-html-fragments) created when using `innerHTML`.)

So, as long as you want to inject a script to the document and make it executed, you have to use `script = document.createElement('script')`.

Set its attributes like `src` and `type`, possibly the contents inside (by using `script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content))`), then append it to the `document.body`.

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution, when you don't have control over the insertion mechanism and you are forced to use innerHTML with `script` beacons, is to rebuild DOM Nodes from the "ghost" ones.

This is a recurring problem in the ad-tech industry, in a which many automated systems duplicate arbitrary HTML code (aka. adservers ^^).

works fine in Chrome:

```
var s = wrap.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = 0; i < s.length ; i++) {
  var node=s[i], parent=node.parentElement, d = document.createElement('script');
  d.async=node.async;
  d.src=node.src;
  parent.insertBefore(d,node);
  parent.removeChild(node);
}
```

(you can [test it in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samuel_29/qe3htbbr/))

Comment: if the script tag contains the javascript directly then you need to assign the `textContent` field instead of (or in addition to) the `src` field.  In any case, +1 for an actual real solution which works for the case where javascript is used client side on a pre-existing HTML template where calling document.createElement is not feasible.

Comment: And also of coure if `textContent` is used, `d.setAttribute('type','text/javascript')` is also required to make sure the text content is evaluated as javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this instead:

```
var wrap = document.createElement('div');
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.src = scriptUrl;
scr.type = 'text/javascript';
wrap.appendChild(scr);
document.body.appendChild(wrap);
```

By creating the script tag explicitly you're telling JS that the innerHTML is not a text but instead it's an executable script.

Comment: hehe,I know that.if you create the script tag with
    
    document.createElement('script')

it just works.and create with innerHTML is how Zepto's $ method realize it