# jQuery AJAX dataType is HTML, which script not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:...,
    dataType:"html",
    success:function(html) {
        $("...").html(html);
    }
});
```

and the URL to controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value="....")
public ModelAndView ....(){
   ......
   return new ModelAndView(........);
}
```

and the HTML is a jsp, it contains HTML and a script like:

```
<div>....</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   ....
</script>
```

but the script is not executing, sometimes it executes... I don't know why. Any ideas as to why this would be happening?

Comment: *"but the script not execute,sometimes it execute"* So, sometimes it "works" and sometimes it doesn't? That's not really much to go with. However, the documentation says about the `.html` methods: *"This method uses the browser's `innerHTML` property."*, and `innerHTML` doesn't evaluate `script` elements. Maybe you are better off with `empty().append()`.

Comment: what kind of script is there

Comment: possible duplicate of [script tag create with innerHTML of a div doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work)