# Hot to append div tag with script tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to invoke script with `<div>`, but it doesn't work.

For example, `alert(101)` was invoked, but `alert(201)` and `alert(202)` wasn't invoked.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>start</p>
    <div id="abc"></div>
    <p>end</p>
    <script>
      // append script (invoked!!)
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      s.innerHTML = 'alert(101);';
      document.getElementById('abc').appendChild(s);

      // append div (not works)
      var d = document.createElement('div');
      // I'm going to try to add a div, script, multi tags.
      // This data will be get via Ajax.
      d.innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(201);<\/script><script type='text/javascript'>alert(202);<\/script>";
      document.getElementById('abc').appendChild(d);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you tell me a solution?

Comment: Why you escape slashes `<\/script>`?

Comment: @jcubic Sorry, I don't understand well. I got a error when not used escape. `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`

Comment: Try ```s.onload = function() {
  alert("202);
};```

Comment: @styopdev Thanks. But I'd like to insert some tags and invoke scripts.

Comment: Read about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13392818/949476

Comment: Sorry my bad, closing `</script>` will close your first open script, not the one in string.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will read it!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
// append script (invoked!!)
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
s.innerHTML = 'alert(101);';
document.getElementById('abc').appendChild(s);

// append div (not works)
var d = document.createElement('div');
var s2 = document.createElement('script');
s2.innerText = 'alert(201)';
d.appendChild(s2);
// I'm going to try to add a div, script, multi tags.
// This data will be get via Ajax.
// d.innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(201);<\/script><script type='text/javascript'>alert(202);<\/script>";
document.getElementById('abc').appendChild(d);
```