# jQuery 3.1.1 violation of CSP directive

Tags: jquery, content-security-policy

I'm using jQuery version 3.1.1 and I'm trying to implement [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) (CSP) directives on my webpage.

I'm getting the following error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'nonce-c20t41c7-73c6-4bf9-fde8-24a7b35t5f71'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-KAcpKskREkEQf5B3mhDTonpPg34XnzaUC5IoBrOUrwY='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

The error is produced on line 82 of the main jquery.js script file. The content of this line is:

```
doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
```

Basically, it adds an inline script tag to the DOM, that violates the CSP.

I do not want to use `'unsafe-inline'`. Is there another way to circumvent this error?

As you can see on the CSP violation, I'm using CSP level 2 (nonce), but it is ignored. Would it be possible (somehow) to inform jQuery to use this nonce when appending the script tag?

---

This is how the HTML looks like (using an [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) template for nonce)

```
<script nonce="<%=nonce%>" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Once the HTML is rendered, the nonce attribute on the script tag matches the CSP nonce directive sent by the server.

---

It does work with plain JavaScript:

```
<script nonce="<%=nonce%>" type="text/javascript">
        var userEmail = "<%=user.user.email%>";
</script>
```

Without the nonce attribute, this script tag would violate the CSP directive.

Comment: does it work with just javascript or if you put directly the script in you html ?

Comment: Have you got a `nonce` attribute set on the script tag matching the CSP's nonce (minus the "nonce-" prefix) prior to appending it to head? Possibly seeing what the script element looks like and the CSP header may help if you're already doing this.

Comment: @bormat Yes, it works with plain javascript.

Comment: @Brian Yes, I have got the nonce attribute on the script tag matching the CSP nonce.

Comment: Just updated the question to reflect comments

Comment: In fact I would like to say that jquery use ajax to load external web script or remove your nonce tag, so you can't load your script with jquery. try instead to use vanilla javascript like this: <script>
 var s = document.createElement('script');
 s.nonce = <%=nonce%>;
 s.src = "putYouUrlHere";
 document.body.appendChild(s)//or document.head;
</script>

Comment: @bormat Maybe I'm not understanding your comment, but I'm not trying to add a script tag programatically. The source code line on my question refers to the JQuery line that violates the CSP directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug or quirk of jQuery how it appends inline scripts ends up discarding all of their attributes and I can't see an obvious way of fixing it
to test it I used the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src http://localhost 'nonce-123456' ; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'nonce-123456';">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js" nonce="123456"></script> <!-- HTML nonce works -->
        <script nonce="123456">
            // This works
            console.log('Inline nonce works');

            // This will also work
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.setAttribute('nonce', '123456');
            s.textContent = 'console.log("Dynamically generated inline tag works")';
            document.head.appendChild(s);

            // This won't work
            var s2 = document.createElement('script');
            s2.setAttribute('nonce', '123456');
            s2.textContent = 'console.log("Dynamically generated inline tag appended via jQuery doesn\'t work")';
            $(document.head).append(s2); // This will throw a CSP error
        </script>
    </head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

When using jQuery to append it goes through the following process (reduced a little):

- Creates a document fragment and appends a script tag to it
- Applies a `type="false/"` attribute to the script tag
- Removes the `type` attribute
- If a `src` attribute is present it retrieves the script via Ajax (didn't investigate this further)
- If not it runs `DOMEval(node.textContent.replace(rcleanScript, ""), doc)`

`DomEval` looks like this (with added comments):

```
doc = doc || document;
var script = doc.createElement( "script" );
script.textContent = code;
doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
```

As you can see, no attributes would carry over to the new element before it was appended and as such CSP fails.

The solution would be to just use native JavaScript to append the element as opposed to jQuery or possibly wait on a bug fix/response to your report. I'm unsure what their reasoning would be to exclude attributes in this manner for inline script tags maybe a security feature?

The following should achieve what you want without jQuery - just set the textContent attribute to your JavaScript source code.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('nonce', '<%=nonce%>');
script.textContent = '// Code here';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

So essentially why that particular line throws the error is that the appended tag is actually a new tag with the same code and no attributes applied to it and as it has no `nonce` it's rejected by CSP.

Update: I've patched jQuery to fix this issue (is 3.1.2-pre patched but passing all tests), if you used my last fix I recommend updating to this version!

Minified: http://pastebin.com/gcLexN7z

Un-minified: http://pastebin.com/AEvzir4H

The branch is available here: https://github.com/Brian-Aykut/jquery/tree/3541-csp

Issue link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3541

Changes in the code:

Line ~76 replace `DOMEval` function with:

```
function DOMEval( code, doc, attr ) {
    doc = doc || document;
    attr = attr || {};
    var script = doc.createElement( "script" );
    for ( var key in attr ) {
        if ( attr.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
            script.setAttribute( key, attr[ key ] );
        }
    }
    script.text = code;
    doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
}
```

Add `attr` to `var` statement on ~line 5717 to

```
var fragment, first, scripts, hasScripts, node, doc, attr,
```

Change `else` body near line 5790 to:

```
attr = {};
if ( node.hasAttribute && node.hasAttribute( "nonce" ) ) {
    attr.nonce = node.getAttribute( "nonce" );
}
DOMEval( node.textContent.replace( rcleanScript, "" ), doc, attr );
```

Comment: One thing that's very strange with this is despite the element being appended with no `nonce` attribute. In my dev tools and before/after the append child there is no attribute looking in the elements pane in Chome dev tools it's magically there and accessible via `s2.getAttribute('nonce')`. By the looks of things perhaps I missed the document fragment being appended BUT that particular script tag doesn't get executed, only the one created appended in `DOMEval` which might explain why it looks all good in elements but CSP is no good :)

Comment: I don't think `.innerHTML` works as expected on `script` elements. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13392818/367865

Comment: You're right @Ouroborus, thanks I've revised so it uses `textContent` - .`innerHTML` can escape things unexpectedly - I'd gotten the two confused! Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Brian, thanks for your analysis and steps to reproduce the problem. Nevertheless, the solution you propose does not solve the issue. JQuery executes DOMEval for every script tag in my subpage removing the nonce attribute and generating a CSP violation.

Comment: @VictorGaspar it's entirely possible that if you're evaluating the script tag with jQuery in any way that it may strip the attributes - DOMEval is called indirectly by many other jQuery internal functions. I've implemented a hack which may help but it's not ideal for many reasons, I think the safer solution would be to avoid jQuery for creating the script elements and appending them as pretty much by the looks if you touch an inline script with it (selector to create tag or appending etc) it's going to remove the nonce. How are you currently processing the scripts (creating  + appending)?

Comment: @VictorGaspar I've made a patched version of jQuery which should retain nonce attributes (at least the ones that go through DOMEval()) if you used my previous patch I recommend replacing it with this as the old one failed quite a few tests and may have some unintended side effects whereas this one passes all tests so should hopefully be fine!

Comment: @Brian +5 for providing a JQuery fix! Hopefully is promoted soon. Thanks!

Comment: @VictorGaspar you're very welcome! I'll be sure to follow the issue and submit a PR if they're happy with my solution. I'll also update the answer once the solution is released so that anyone coming here in future knows the minimum version of jQuery required to avoid this issue :).

Answer (score 2):

OK, you just want to include jQuery, so you need to redefined the function appendChild (to disable it) before the jQuery script and after delete your custom function.

```
<script>
    var oldAppend = document.head.appendChild
    document.head.appendChild = function(script){
        if(script && script.tagName=='SCRIPT'){
            document.createElement('fakeHead').appendChild(script)//because script need a parent in the line that create the error
            return script
        }
        return oldAppend.apply(this,arguments)
    }
</script>

<script nonce="<%=nonce%>" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    document.head.appendChild = oldAppend
</script>
```

Try this. It will redefine the append function of jQuery:

```
var oldAppend = $.fn.append
$.fn.append = function($el){
    var dom = ($el instanceOf $) ? $el[0] : $el
    if(dom && dom.tagName=='SCRIPT'){
        this[0].appendChild(dom)
        return this
    }
    return oldAppend.apply(this,arguments)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately your workaround does not solve the issue that JQuery strips script attributes when executing the DOMEval function.

Comment: I have edited, in fact jquery only keep src and as attribute and remove all others