# JQuery 3.5.1 and Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I upgraded jQuery from 2.1.1 to 3.5.1 and I started seeing this issue with jQuery

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'nonce-YURLOAQRrIwdGEqYSSpHx9YSWDM......' 'unsafe-eval'".
> Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-2mvMk0Nvn96VqS1UEmAZSVSEkK0CkPN....'), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I do not want to use 'unsafe-inline'.

The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3541) , [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3969) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450608/jquery-3-1-1-violation-of-csp-directive) in 2017-2018. I thought the issue is resolved by now in jQuery 3.5.1 unless I am missing something.

My application is developed in .NET Core 5.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" asp-add-nonce="true"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <button type="button" id="btnGetContent">Get Content</button>

    <div id="result">
        <partial name="_Test" />
    </div>    

    <script src="~/js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**_Test.cshtml Partial View**

```
@System.DateTime.Now.ToString();

<script type="text/javascript" asp-add-nonce="true">    
   // partial view specific inline script
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnGetContent").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",            
            url: "/test/getcontent",            
            processData: true,
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // in browser's console I notice the error at this line
            $("#result").html(response);
        })          
    })   
})
```

**Controller**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetContent()
    {
        return PartialView("_Test");
    }
}
```

**CSP policy**

```
"default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-{0}' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; child-src 'self';"
```

I have custom `asp-add-nonce` tag helper and a nonce middleware. ** For each request ** the tag helper and the middleware inject new nonce value into script tag and CSP policy respectively, and this has been working fine.

After I upgraded jQuery to 3.5.1, looks like jQuery also need nonce value in script tag so I have added `asp-add-nonce="true"` in header like
`<script src="~/lib/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" asp-add-nonce="true"></script>`

**ISSUE**
I think the issue here, Since nonce value is created for each http request, and jQuery is loaded only once per page. `Get Content` request creates new value which of-course does not match with original value that was injected in jQuery script tag. So we get error `Refused to execute inline script...`

Is there anyway to resolve this without adding nonce to jQuery's script tag?

**UPDATE 1**
After looking the CSP report submitted by browser, it reveled more details. The violated directive is actually `script-src-elem`. My CSP policy does not even have that directive. This directive is available in CSP 3 version. Not sure why browser is erroring out on jQuery for this directive.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
You can [download repository](https://github.com/laksh-parab/cspjq) to re-produce the issue

Comment: As the error message said, when you click the `Get Content` button to add the partial view with the `<script>` tag, it violates the following Content Security Policy directive. You could consider removing the `<script>` tag in the `_TestPartialView` partial view and add the related script content in the home.js. In the home.js file, after document ready and load the partial view, attach the relates event and function (come from the _TestPartialView `<script>` tag).

Comment: We cannot. This is existing application. There are several pages where partial views are rendered dynamically and those partial views have their own `script` tag with nonce. This was working before JQ update to 3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Well based on my related Questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406073/jquery-3-5-1-and-csp-script-src-elem) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410153/csp-does-browser-check-if-the-nonce-value-in-header-matches-with-the-nonce-valu) I think I will have to add `script-src unsafe-inline` for jQuery 3.1+ to work properly in the following scenario

1>You are using jQuery 3.1+
2>jQuery is added on _layout page or main page so it load only once at start.
3>You are loading partial content using AJAX.

In `nonce` approach it is recommended to use unique `nonce` for each http request. But his approach will not work here. Because AJAX call will get different nonce in header. So any jQuery call after will not work.

For me it was working with 2.1.1 because `jQuery 2.x parses all <script>...</script> tags from the HTML and puts it in a dynamically generated script tag or executes those through eval( )` [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410153/csp-does-browser-check-if-the-nonce-value-in-header-matches-with-the-nonce-valu) and I had `script-src nonce-xyz unsafe-eval`

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. Did you just remove nonce form CSP header and added 'unsafe-inline'? Because if you add both then it ignores 'unsafe-inline'

Comment: @LP13 Do you have a reference regarding statement that AJAX is getting a different nonce for each call?
Here is opposite question was risen how to make AJAX to get different nonce each call https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83563/how-to-get-a-unique-nonce-for-each-ajax-request  
Is it correct as per 2022 ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is happen due to chrome extensions, chrome extensions trying to execute some operation in website and website blocking it. Issue is with BlazeMeter chrome extension.

So just remove chrome extensions and then try again. Or Check with another browser.