# CSP: Does browser check if the nonce value in header matches with the nonce value in script tag?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, asp.net-core, microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

I have a page that loads partial content using Ajax. The partial content has `script` tag whose nonce value DOES NOT match with the nonce defined in the `Content-Security-Policy` header.

Here is the complete code (using asp.net core + jQuery 2.1.1)

**Middleware**
For every http request middleware will inject `Content-Security-Policy` header with nonce value

```
public class CSPMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CSPMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;            
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        
        context.Response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = $"default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-abc' 'unsafe-eval'";

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<button type="button" id="btnGetContent">Get Partial View</button>

<div id="result">    
</div>

//this script on the main page will execute since nonce matches with the header
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="abc">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGetContent").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/getpartialview",
                processData: true,
                cache: false
            })
                .done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $("#result").html(response);
                })
        })

        
    })
</script>
```

**Partial View**

```
@System.DateTime.Now.ToString();

<button id="btn2">Click Me. I am on Partial</button>

// this script should not execute since nonce does not match
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="xyz">
    $("#btn2").click(function () {
        alert("foo");
    })
</script>
```

My expectation is, the click event on partial view should NOT fire because script's nonce value does not match with the header. However click event does get fire.

Does browser checks if the nonce value in `Content-Security-Policy` header matches with nonce value in script tag?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, browser exactly check matches nonce values in the header and in the script tag. But jQuery 2.x (unintentionally) uses a technique to bypass `'nonce-value'` via `'unsafe-eval'` (you had to allow evalfor that).
This framework brokes all logics of placing scripts in the HTML code.

jQuery 2.x parses all `<script>...</script>` tags from the HTML and puts it in a dynamically generated script tag or executes those through `eval( )`:
[image]

That's why Dropbox performs manual checking of `nonce` for jQuery 2.x:
[image]

More details you can find in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBBqtrJmMRc&list=PLpr-xdpM8wG8RHOguwOZhUHkKiDeWpvFp&t=1883s) from AppSec EU 2017 (already rewinded to the required moment).

Comment: Thanks. I think I can decide if I need to add `unsafe-inline`  This was my original issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377168/jquery-3-5-1-and-refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-it-violates-the-follow/67423065#67423065