# Why the dynamic script does not execute？

Tags: javascript

the code in the dynamic script does not execute:

```
var script = document.createElement('div')
script.innerHTML = `<script>alert('asd')<\/script>`
document.body.appendChild(script)
```

while the code below works:

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
var script = document.createElement('script')
script.text = `alert('asd')`
div.appendChild(script)
document.body.appendChild(div)
```

what the different and why?

Comment: It does execute.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean now. Why doesn't the alert fire?

Comment: @Worthy7 yes, that's what i mean

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: [Advantages of createElement over innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2946656/3898339) Question

Comment: ... and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)