# How to insert and execute script tag to the DOM using plain js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to insert any string like `<script>console.log('it works');</script>`  into browser DOM and see "it works" in browser console then?

jQuery's append function doing the thing:
`$('html').append('<script>console.log('it works');`
but I am looking for light solution, ideally plain js

context: the string can be complex like `<div><h1>Title</h1></div><div><script>console.log('it works');</script></div>` - it should renders correct in the DOM and do all the JS staff

Comment: You have to create the `<script>` element explicitly.  Inserting it via `innerHTML` will ***intentionally*** not work as defined by the spec.

Comment: See [script tag create with innerHTML of a div doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392818/691711).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [script tag create with innerHTML of a div doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML` to insert the HTML, then go back and look for the scripts and copy the script `src` or text, and insert the copy into the DOM to run it:

```js
// Sticking with broadly-supported features:
var htmlString = "<div><h1>Title</h1></div><div><script>console.log('it works');<\/script></div>";
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlString);
var scripts = target.getElementsByTagName("script");
while (scripts.length) {
    var script = scripts[0];
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
    var newScript = document.createElement("script");
    if (script.src) {
        newScript.src = script.src;
    } else if (script.textContent) {
        newScript.textContent = script.textContent;
    } else if (script.innerText) {
        newScript.innerText = script.innerText;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

**Note:** Any inline `document.write` statements will **not** work as they would in the initial parse of a page; instead, they'll re-open the document and replace all of its content with whatever they write.

Comment: Supplementary blog post regarding `Element.insertAdjacentHTML` method: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/insertadjacenthtml-enables-faster-html-snippet-injection/