# Run HTML and JavaScript from String

Tags: javascript, html, templates

i would like to render a string which contains html and javascript. Its neccessary that the Javascript is interpreted like jQuerys `$.load()` does - but without jQuery.

Here is an example of what i try to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/4tfcypq6/

Vue.js is used as frontend-framework

Comment: Is this really necessary? "Eval is evil". Consider explaining your case.

Comment: Unfortunately it is necessary. I get an external string, which I want to display as a page. But the Javascript is part of it and is needed for the correct display with all functions.

Comment: There's a good chance that the problem could be solved in another way because evaluating arbitrary strings is ineffective, potentially unsafe and should be the last resort, also depends on where a string comes from. As it was noted in deleted comment, it's unclear what it has in common with Vue, this is certainly not how Vue is usually used. Please, consider explaining your case in detail, this is how good questions are asked on SO, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . A good answer would explain how it should be done in your situation and probably suggest better ways to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work and several other similar questions. TL;DR: after creating nodes with innerHTML, you need to replace dummy `script` nodes with newly created `document.createElement("script")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var htmlJsString = ('<div id="home">Hi</div>'+eval('document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = "Welcome";'))
```

Please check the link https://jsfiddle.net/28za6rm3/