# Why XSS doesn't work at a created HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Hello I'm practice on XSS-Attack in an HTML Page that I created, but it doesn't work for me.
This is the HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Try to XSS this!</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var send = function () {
            var data = document.getElementById("msg").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter an XSS exploit here:</p>
    <textarea id="msg" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="send" onclick="send();"/>
    <br>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the XSS-Exploit (I write it in the `<textarea>`):

```
hello</p>
<script>alert("XSS");</script>
<p>
```

And this is the result (I show the `<p id="demo"></p>` part):

```
<p id="demo">
    "hello"
    <p></p>
    <script>alert("XSS");</script>
    <p></p>
</p>
```

And the command `alert("XSS");` doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Html5 does not executes `innerHTML`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations and https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [script tag create with innerHTML of a div doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work)

Comment: So how can I write the exploit? I don't want to change the HTML Page because of the practice. I replaced the ```innerHTML``` in the "demo" tag with ```textContent``` but it doesn't work. This is the result:

Comment: ```<p id="demo">hello</p>
<script>alert("XSS");</script>
<p></p>```

Comment: @SomeOne Did you read the first link Justinas provided? It actually mentions "_However, there are ways to execute JavaScript without using `<script>` elements_" with an example. Try `<img src='x' onerror='alert("XSS");'>` as input.

Answer (score 0):

Script tags only run on page load; when you dynamically inject them into the page, script tags aren't run. The common bypass to this is to use `onerror` or `onload` like `<img src=x onerror='alert(1)'>` or `<svg onload='alert(1)'></svg>`