# Reactjs and script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a blog with reactJS. However dangerouslySetInnerHTML doesn't render scripts in blog posts.

Those blog posts contain twitter widgets, or github embeds etc

is there a way to do this?

Comment: The reason why scripts don't load via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work/13392818#13392818

Answer (score 1):

You can always include those scripts in your index.html file. If you want to add these script files conditionally, Here is how you can do it.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 568px)").matches) {
    script.src = "//path/to/mobile-users.js";
} else {
    script.src = "//path/to/desktop-users.js";
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: that's impossible to do with github gist e.g. `<script src="https://gist.github.com/frodoslaw/863cd7207f0736b075d9c5e6604f614e.js"></script>`